# How to reference the EditText inside a NumberPicker?

Tags: android, android-edittext, numberpicker

I need to get the reference to the EditText inside a NumberPicker. I know it's going to be some sort of findViewById on the picker view itself, but I haven't been able to find android's id for it:

```
final NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.numberpicker);
EditText numberPickerEditText = (EditText) numberPicker.findViewById(WHAT IS THE ID???)
```

I know NumberPicker has most of the useful methods for the value etc., but I need some finer control such as displaying the keyboard when the picker opens and I don't think I can do this without a reference to the EditText itself (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong in this!)

Comment: can u please share complete code?

Comment: how complete do you need? The xml of my NumberPicker? I don't know what else is relevant, but please advise...

Comment: Show me your java class bro and also xml of your numberpicker

Comment: you are using default android number picker or customized it ?

Comment: default picker, standard, just needed reference to EditText, as I think I've found. Trying to keep answer Minimal, Complete and Verifiable, posting whole class here irrelevant I think... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I m glad you found the solution. Best of luck buddy :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would look at the `xml` file being used by the `NumberPicker` you'll find that the `id` of the `EditText` you're looking for is `numberpicker_input` :

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/increment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/numberpicker_up_btn"
        android:paddingTop="22dip"
        android:paddingBottom="22dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/number_picker_increment_button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numberpicker_input"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Large.Inverse.NumberPickerInputText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@drawable/numberpicker_input" />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/decrement"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/numberpicker_down_btn"
        android:paddingTop="22dip"
        android:paddingBottom="22dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/number_picker_decrement_button" />

</merge>
```

So, you can do it by using the same `id`:

```
NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.numberpicker);
EditText numberPickerEditText = (EditText) numberPicker.findViewById(R.id.numberpicker_input)
```

**EDIT**

Ok, so looks like this `id` is inside `android.internal.id`, since it's a system id, to be able to access it you'll have to do this:

```
numberPicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("numberpicker_input", "id", "android"))
```

Comment: that's not working for me - I haven't defined this id anywhere in my XML, and I tried   android.R.id.numberpicker_input and that didn't work either

Comment: ok, yes numberpicker_input definitely isn't working for me... sorry for what may be a silly question, how - in android studio - can I see NumberPicker's layout xml?

Comment: it should've worked, let me check, btw you can see it by pressing `Ctrl + B`, it'll take you to the `NumberPicker` class, there you can find `EditText`, and again pressing `Ctrl+B` on its `id` will take you to the `xml`

Comment: Ok, this seems to get a reference to it! I'll keep testing and see if I can use it, setting Text etc. seems to be overridden by numberpicker, but no errors!! Thanks!

Comment: btw did you find the `NumberPicker`'s `xml`?, you've to press the 1st `Ctrl+B` on `NumberPicker`, either in your `xml` or `Java`

Answer (score 0):

You can show soft keyboard without reference to edit-text

```
getWindow()
.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: hi, I'm displaying the numberpicker inside an AlertDialog that I'm creating programatically, using AlertDialog.Builder... where would I put this code??

Comment: just put the line when your Alert Dialog is open or  on Onclick event to open Alert Dialog

Comment: I'll give that a try and see if it opens the keyboard when dialog .show() is called, I would still love to be able to reference EditText also though!

Answer (score -1):

you have to create a view and inflate it

```
View yourView = li.inflate(R.layout.your_view, null);
```

After that tou have to initialize your editText as:

```
EditText yourEditText = (EditText) yourView.findViewById(R.id.text_symbol);
```

It will surely work... Give it a try and let me know if it works for you 
Happy coding bro :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of what ID to use to get the EditText inside a NumberPicker.